# laravel 8 repository class not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

in my new laravel project i have created a repository folder in the root folder of the project, in that folder there is a BankRequests folder with BankRequestRepository file in it,like this:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Repositories\BankRequests\BankRequestRepository;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class PaymentRequestController extends Controller

{
    private $bankRequestRepository;
public function __construct( BankRequestRepository $bankRequestRepository)
{
    $this->bankRequestRepository = $bankRequestRepository;
}

public function payeeValidation(Request $request)
{
    dd(1234);
    $verifiedPayees= array();
    foreach ($request->payees as $payee ){
        $ibanOwners= $this->bankRequestRepository->shebaCheck($payee);
        $ibanOwnerKey= array_search($payee,$ibanOwners);
        $ibanOwner= $ibanOwners[$ibanOwnerKey];
        array_push($verifiedPayees, $ibanOwner);
    }
    return $verifiedPayees;
}
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
```

}

in my paymentRequestController i use the repository like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Repositories\BankRequests\BankRequestRepository;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class PaymentRequestController extends Controller
{
    private $bankRequestRepository;

public function __construct( BankRequestRepository $bankRequestRepository)
{
    $this->bankRequestRepository = $bankRequestRepository;
}

public function payeeValidation(Request $request)
{
    dd(1234);
    $verifiedPayees= array();
    foreach ($request->payees as $payee ){
        $ibanOwners= $this->bankRequestRepository->shebaCheck($payee);
        $ibanOwnerKey= array_search($payee,$ibanOwners);
        $ibanOwner= $ibanOwners[$ibanOwnerKey];
        array_push($verifiedPayees, $ibanOwner);
    }
    return $verifiedPayees;
}
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
}
```

when i call the
`Route::post('payment-request/payee-validation', [PaymentRequestController::class, 'payeeValidation']);` 
it returns error:
"message": "Target class [App\Repositories\BankRequests\BankRequestRepository] does not exist.",

i used to do it like this in older laravel releases with no problem. is this a laravel 8 kind of problem?

Comment: Does the namespace in the `BankRequestRepository` class match `App\Repositories\BankRequests\BankRequestRepository`?

Comment: "_in the root folder of the project_" In the _root_ folder or in the _app_ folder?

Comment: @brombeer root folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use `use App\Repositories\BankRequests\BankRequestRepository;` your `repositories/` folder should be placed inside the `app/` folder, not the root folder. Also make sure that you're using `namespace App\Repositories\BankRequests` in your repository file.

After moving your folder (and maybe editing your namespace) run `composer dumpautoload` for composer to pick up those changes.